# How is the effect of current vote scores on people's votes interpreted in psychology?

Tags: social-psychology, communication, internet

On a site that people can vote on others' posts (like Stack Exchange sites), I believe people tend to be affected by the current vote score (and for Stack Exchange, if the user has enough reputation, the current vote counts as well) before they cast a vote, or even more, before they decide to whether cast a vote. A typical case is illustrated by [this Reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/TheoryOfReddit/comments/4gul4w/the_psychology_of_downvoting/),

> I tend to upvote people who have been downvoted out of sympathy.

The linked Reddit post already contains part of the answer but it's more like a subjective discussion so I am not satisfied with it.

Can somebody elaborate on what effects can take place in this process? What is effect on the final vote count/score if we consider it as a whole? Are there any known terminology or models to describe this behavior?

I am new to psychology so any hint will be helpful.

---

Related: [Why do people make rants on Meta Stack Exchange sites?](https://psychology.stackexchange.com/questions/4566/why-do-people-make-rants-on-meta-stack-exchange-sites)

Comment: I'll personally down vote your question out of fun and just so you could feel it yourself, maybe you understand it better :)

Comment: @Veljko89 Thank you for what you did and what you didn't do.

Answer (score 3):

I think you can find an answer from the field of social psychology. The most relevant theory is the [social proof](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Social_proof), the tendency to immitate the behavior of other people.

> Social proof (also known as informational social influence) is a
>   psychological and social phenomenon where people assume the actions of
>   others in an attempt to reflect correct behavior in a given situation.
>
> ...
>
> Social proof is one type of conformity. When a person is in a
>   situation where they are unsure of the correct way to behave, they
>   will often look to others for clues concerning the correct behavior.
>   When "we conform because we believe that others' interpretation of an
>   ambiguous situation is more accurate than ours and will help us choose
>   an appropriate course of action", it is informational social
>   influence.

Comment: Thank you very much. I will look into that but I think it is more than that because maybe it cannot explain the situation in Veljko89's comment.

Comment: @WeijunZhou Certaintly there are many effects that infuelnce our behavior, social proof is just one of them. The sympathy you mention is another effect.